# Does every morphism $\mathcal F\to \mathcal G$ induce a morphism of sheaves $\mathcal F^{\dagger}\to \mathcal G^{\dagger}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $\mathcal F,\mathcal G$ be presheaves of Abelian groups on topological space $X$. Does every morphism $\mathcal F\to \mathcal G$ induce a morphism of sheaves $\mathcal F^{\dagger}\to \mathcal G^{\dagger}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [sheafification is a functor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sheafification). It is left adjoint to the
forgetful functor from sheaves to presheaves.